# Screen Translation?

Tags: localization

How can the text in a **running** app be translated?

Ideally, I would like it to be automatic, like the translation *Google Chrome Desktop* does.

Second best solution, If the above is not possible, to be able to translate a screenshot taken from the device (without using a PC, and preferably without internet connection).

[image: Screenshot of app in Norwegian]
[image: Screenshot of app in English]

I have tried to translate the screenshot with *Google Translate* and *Google Goggles* (Thanx @forums), but the former can only work with the camera, and not with a stored file, where as the later does not correctly identify all texts (see comments below).

OS/Device (if that matters): Android 4.2.2, LG Nexus 4

Comment: Theres an app called in app translator does this job

Answer (score 1):

I use [Google Goggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.unveil) to scan barcodes, qr codes, objects, and also translate foreign aliens :P

It also has an option to open images from gallery including screenshots. Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of any in-app translation app. The developer should be responsible for that matter

Comment: Developers are irresponsible here :P. Thanx I will give it a try...

Comment: Tried it but I could not set OCR language. Also, it does not recognize all the parts with text. Could not figure out how to manually select area for OCR. But it is a cool App anyway!